# Async Mysql Query in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await

I want to get a specific value from my mysql database and then pass it to an API. So I have to wait for the query to finish. I found this async/await example on stackoverflow. But it's not working for me.

```
async function getUTC() {
  try {
    let result = await db.query(`SELECT utcEndSeconds FROM mp_games ORDER BY utcEndSeconds ASC LIMIT 1`)
    return result
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

let newUTC = getUTC()
console.log(newUTC)

newUTC.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

The first console.log(newUTC) prints Promise { pending }. I expected to find my data here, because await should already resolve the promise???

Then I added the .then() block. console.log(data) prints a big object (mysql I guess) but my data is nowhere to be found in the object.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with understanding of async/await pattern.

```
newUTC.then(data => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

the above code resolves promise and return you `data` object. but `console.log(newUTC)` gives you promise pending because it is not awaited nor encapsulated with promise for resolution.

if you change

```
let newUTC = getUTC()
console.log(newUTC)
```

to

```
let newUTC = getUTC()
console.log(await newUTC)
```

then first the code awaited and the result is passed to the `console.log`.

EDIT: await only works within async function. IF your function is not async then you need to use promise approach.

```
let newUTC = getUTC()
newUTC.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: which means the function is not async. then you need to use promise. check my edit

Comment: if you check my code again you will see that I use that exact code at the end. My problem is that I cant find my data (the utcTimestamp I'm looking for) in the data object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use mysql.query callback function and run the rest of my code inside. It's not as pretty but works

```
db.query(`SELECT utcEndSeconds FROM mp_games ORDER BY utcEndSeconds ASC LIMIT 1`, (err, result) => {
  let newUTC = result[0].utcEndSeconds

... rest of my code (api calls etc...)

}
```